# How to implement HLS common encryption media

Tags: nginx, encryption, wowza, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I want to encrypy my HLS media using common encryption. Is there any third party tool can I use ? I could achieve AES 128 encryption from Bento SDK I want to achieve Common encryption for HLS appreciate if someone can help

Comment: Anyone can help on this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I realize that HLS does not completely support common encryption. It supports two types of encryption

1. AES 128 encryption
2. Sample AES encryption

This sample AES encryption supported by fairplay (DRM provider by Apple). So in that case if we want to implement EME for HLS media you can only support Safari. Besides HLS DASH media 100%  supports common encryption. So if you anyone want to implement EME better use DASH hope this helps someone